# passing data into Bootstrap modals

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the below modal and call to the modal:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-val="xxx "data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">Launch demo modal</button>
```

What I am trying to do, is take the data-val element in the button and pass it into the URL of the modal (replace bxw8pq with whatever data-val is equal to)

I have used this JS to just try and pass the data to the modal & it doesn't work (doesn't do anything at all!)

```
 <script>
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    var vidid = $(e.relatedTarget).data('val');
    $(this).find(".modal-body").text(vidid);
});     
        </script>
```

Do you know how I can make this JS work & also how I can pass the value to the specific part of the string in the modal?

Thanks!!!!

---

Demo added by community:

```js
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
  var vidid = $(e.relatedTarget).data('val');
  $(this).find(".modal-body").text(vidid);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-Dop/vW3iOtayerlYAqCgkVr2aTr2ErwwTYOvRFUpzl2VhCMJyjQF0Q9TjUXIo6JhuM/3i0vVEt2e/7QQmnHQqw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-val="Data value here!" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Launch demo modal</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabelDefault" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabelDefault">Modal title</h5>
      </div>
      
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div style="width:100%;height:0px;position:relative;padding-bottom:56.250%;"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800"></div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-oBTprMeNEKCnqfuqKd6sbvFzmFQtlXS3e0C/RGFV0hD6QzhHV+ODfaQbAlmY6/q0ubbwlAM/nCJjkrgA3waLzg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: You're mixing Bootstrap 3 and Bootstrap 5 syntax. `data-bs-modal` is a version 5 attribute name. I'll be surprised if version 3 responds to it.

Comment: Thanks, is there an alternative for other versions?

Comment: Are you not referencing the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals)?

Comment: I updated your markup in a demo snippet to match the documentation and it works as expected. Voting to close. I do suggest that you move to a modern Bootstrap version, though.